# C# Concurrent Data Structure which can be Iterated through

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, concurrency

I am looking for a thread safe concurrent data structure which I am able to iterate though. order does not matter to me.

I want to have a `Collection` of `Objects`.

One thread will be iterating through this collection continuously calling each objects `Object.Add(Item)`

eg:

```
 Collection<Object> collection = new Collection<Object>();

 //Run On New thread
 while(tasksAvaliable)
 {
  foreach(var item in collection)
  {
   item.Add(task);    //I get tasks from a Concurrent Queue
  }
 }
```

In another thread / timer , it will attempt to try Add, Edit, Remove these objects from the collection. (however less frequently than the other thread)

What Collection Can I use? I am currently Using a concurrent Bag. But I am not sure that when I use a foreach on it that every `Object` in the collection will receive my `Task` which I provide it in the foreach loop.

I was thinking alternatively I could use a normal `List<Object>` and simply lock it when I Add,edit, or remove objects from it. However objects which I am not working with will get blocked. Which i would prefer to miss, ie I would prefer a fine grain lock.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do here. Can you give us a bit more concrete information? As written, you're going to add `task` to every `item` multiple times, unless those `item` references are removed from the collection. It's *possible* that `ConcurrentBag<T>` will do what you want, but my experience has been that it's generally not the solution to most problems. Also, you should look into using `BlockingCollection` rather than `ConcurrentQueue` for your collection of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class (wrapper) on `IList`, which provide threadsafe access or try use `ConcurrentBag<T>`